# I'm having a problem when I press the keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

When I touch the keyboard it has such a height. This also gives an overflowed error

Comment: depends on scaffold body, try to wrap with scrollable widget like SingleChildScollview. It would be easier if you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need the Scrolling effect in your screen, It's best to adjust all the elements inside a `SingleChildScrollView()` widget. But if you think you won't need that. All you want is to get rid of the jumping from bottom, the easiest way you can achieve this is by enabling this
`resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,`
in your `Scaffold()` widget.